# 'SDL_SetVideoMode': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I have a problem with SDL lib. I'm using VS2012 Ultimate and i was actually using this tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php to set everything and i did it step by step few times, but I still have problems this is my code, very simple:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <SDL.h>

SDL_Surface * ekran = NULL;

int main (int argc, char *args [] )
{
   SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
   ekran = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
   SDL_Flip( ekran );
   SDL_Delay( 2000 );
   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
}
```

and im having this errors:

```
error C3861: 'SDL_SetVideoMode': identifier not found
error C3861: 'SDL_Flip': identifier not found
```

Comment: What is your compile/link line?

Comment: Which version of SDL are you using?

Comment: I guess you installed SDL 2.0.3, the APIs in version 1 and 2 are very different. However, lazyfoo.net also provide guides about version 2.

Answer (score 6):

Here below is an example how to replace SDL_SetVideoMode() in SDL2. The old way to init SDL is commented and left along with the new way for comparison purposes. Basically, SDL2 creates a window with a title, then a surface attached to it, while SDL1 creates a surface alone and then calls the window manager to give it a name.

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL video init failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}

// SDL_Surface *screenSurface = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Sphere Rendering", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
    SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

if (window == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Window could not be created: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}

screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

if (!screenSurface) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Screen surface could not be created: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
}

// SDL_WM_SetCaption("Sphere Rendering", NULL);
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at that tutorial page again.  Your code does not match it (e.g. SDL_SetVideoMode() no longer exists).  Your code uses SDL 1.2 and the (updated) tutorial uses SDL 2.0.  Are you using an old cached version of that page?